# Not Receiving Entire JSON Payload in Angular 8

Tags: php, angular, api

When receiving a JSON payload, I only receive values in the first object.

On the PHP side, everything seems fine. I constructed a basic two-pocket associative array. In the browser, the JSON encoded object appears to be correct, and the response payload (from the browser's Network tab.) verifies in JSON validator.

Here's the PHP $info array printed to the screen:

```
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [id] => 3
      [first] => June
      [last] => Cleaver
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [hvp] => 1
      [rd] => 1
      [th] => 1
    )
)

echo json_encode($info, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Here's the JSON object which successfully verifies:

```
[
   {
      "id":"3",
      "first":"June",
      "last":"Cleaver"
   },
   {
      "hvp":"1",
      "rd":"1",
      "th":"1"
   }
]
```

Response Payload (from the browser's Network tab.):

```
[{"id":"3","first":"June","last":"Cleaver"},
{"hvp":"1","rd":"1","th":"1"}]
```

When I fetch the payload through an Angular API service, the second Object is empty.

```
Object(2)
  ​0: Object { id: "3", first: "June", last: "Cleaver" }
  1: Object {}
```

I was expecting:

```
Object(2)
  ​0: Object { id: "3", first: "June", last: "Cleaver" }
  1: Object { hvp: "1", rd: "1", th: "1" }
```

Below are the two blocks of code in Angular responsible for fetching the API data. The first is in the component.ts file in question:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.apiService.readPolicies().subscribe((policies:
  Policy[])=>{this.policies = policies;)
  console.log(this.policies);
}
```

This is in the api.service.ts file:

```
readPolicies():Observable<Policy[{
  return this.httpClient.get<Policy[(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}
  /read.php`);
}
```

The **read.php** file appears to do exactly what it's supposed to so I didn't post it.

Policy.ts

```
export interface Policy {
  id: number,
  first: string,
  last: string,
  hvp?: string,
  rd?: string,
  th?: string
}
```

To put a fine point on my issue, the Observable is obviously seeing two objects, but why aren't the key/value pairs in the second object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no way this was going to be solved with the information I provided and that's on me. Turns out, even though my *read.php* script did what it was supposed to, **rxjs** didn't agree. So, I rewrote the script in stronger procedural style and it worked. I had modified the original downloaded script and to my credit it worked, but the sloppy nature of the programming didn't fly. **The lesson here: don't be sloppy.**

Answer (score 0):

Your second object is missing the required parameters from your typescript interface `Policy`. You probably need to make all 6 parameters in `Policy` optional to support your use case

Comment: This should not affect the json parsing, since types aren't checked at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`[{"id":"3","first":"June","last":"Cleaver"},
{"hvp":"1","rd":"1","th":"1"}]` maps to an array with 2 objects. It should rather be:

```
{
    "id": "3",
    "first": "June",
    "last": "Cleaver",
    "hvp": "1",
    "rd": "1",
    "th": "1"
}
```

This way it matches your `Policy` defined in the ts.

Comment: Not sure how to interpret your answer, but I want the JSON data to be two objects. Even if I didn't have ***hvp***, ***rd*** and ***th*** in Policy.ts, would it prevent it from being displayed in the Console?